# retorno CoreDat - Swift

Tags: string, swift, int

Não estou conseguindo atribuir um textField com o resultado de uma busca quando é int, com String da certo

```
 var results:NSArray =  try context.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [NSManagedObject]

        if(results.count > 0){
            var res = results[0] as! NSManagedObject

            nomeText.text = res.valueForKey("nome") as? String
            idadeText.text = res.valueForKey("idade") as? String
               print(res.valueForKey("idade") as? String)
            }
```

No print ele me retorna nil.. quando muda pra Int, ele me retorna valor correto..
como devo fazer para atribuir o textField com esse valor, lembrando que com o campo nome eu não tenho esse erro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sintaxe "as?" retorna nil se não consegue fazer o cast, e neste caso o valor é do tipo Int, então o correto seria assim:

```
res.valueForKey("idade") as? Int
```

Mas, você deveria aproveitar da tipagem de objetos, que o CoreData lhe oferece.

Basta entrar no arquivo xcdatamodel, selecionar suas entidades, e através do menu superior Editor ->  Create NSManagedObject subclass

Assim, seu codigo seria bem mais simples:

```
var results =  try context.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [Pessoa]

if(results.count > 0){
   var res = results[0]

   nomeText.text = res.nome
   idadeText.text = res.idade.description
}
```

Fonte:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-core_data_modeling_tool/Articles/creating_mo_class.html

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Fernando, eu sabia que teria que ser do as? Int, só não estava conseguindo colocar no textField.
Segui seus conselhos e deu certo
 só tive que colocar ! em 
idadeText.text = res.idade!.description

Comment: o sinal de "!" é necessário caso o seu atributo seja marcado como Optional (um "?" junto ao tipo), podendo neste caso ficar com o valor nil. Através da interface gráfica do arquivo xcdatamodel, você pode customisar isso.

Comment: Dei uma lida mais sobre isso, aqui http://themsaid.github.io/2015/04/16/core-data-from-scratch-with-swift/

Mais uma vez obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Os valores númericos em CoreData são mapeados para `NSNumber`.

Para atribuir como texto ao `UITextField` você deve explicitamente pedir o valor como string:

```
let idade : NSNumber = res.valueForKey("idade")
idadeText.text =  idade.stringValue()
```

Comment: Obrigado, ficou um pouco diferente, acredito por causa da versão do swift

            let idade: NSNumber = res.valueForKey("idade") as! Int
            idadeText.text = idade.stringValue

Comment: Fique a vontade para editar a questão . Eu sou programador ObjC ainda não estou acostumado com a sintaxe do `swift`. Adcionalmente se a respota lhe foi útil conside aceitá-la como correta.

Comment: Opa, desculpa.. sou novo aqui e não estava achando onde marcava.. e meu voto por enquanto não computa :/ ,
mas obrigado mais uma vez